# compute $\left|<\tau^2>\right|$ for the given permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

$\tau = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5&6\\2&4&1&3&6&5\end{array}\right)$

I need to compute $|\langle  \tau^2\rangle|$

I know $\tau^2 = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5&6\\4&3&2&1&5&6\end{array}\right)$

but know how do I do $\Bigg|\Bigg\langle\left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5&6\\4&3&2&1&5&6\end{array}\right) \Bigg\rangle\Bigg|$ ?

Its the size of the group generated by $\tau^2$?

Comment: Note that : $(\tau^2)^n$ always fix $5$ and $6$, now you can work with a shorter permutation, for every $n$

Comment: I think I found something similar,  the order will be
$lcm((1 \, 2 \, 3 \, 4)(5 \, 6)) = 4$

Comment: I meant:
  the order will be
$lcm((1 \, 2)( 3 \, 4)(5 \, 6)) = 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sigma = \tau^2$; then we are interested in $|\langle\sigma\rangle|$. What is $\langle\sigma\rangle$? Notice that $\sigma^2 = e$. Therefore the group generated by $\sigma$ (the set of powers and inverse powers of $\sigma$) is simply $\{e,\sigma\}$. So your answer is $2$.

Comment: okay, this is similar to my comment correct? not the first one, the second one (couldn't edit the first after 5 minutes). theres 3 disjoint cycles, each with 2 elements and so the lcm is 2

Comment: The idea is correct, but your cycle decomposition is incorrect. The correct decomposition is $\tau = (1243)(56)$. And the decomposition of $\tau$ isn't really important; what is important is the decomposition of $\tau^2 = (14)(23)$. With this, your idea work,s